# What is the Enterprise-E's crew complement?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng

How many people are on board the Enterprise-E? There were over 1000 people aboard the Enterprise-D. I know the Enterprise-D was slightly bigger; would the crew complement of the Enterprise-E be a lot less?

Comment: [Memory-Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Enterprise_(NCC-1701-E)) suggests about 700-800

Comment: "You look really good in that uniform."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this](http://techspecs.acalltoduty.com/sovereign.html), on a Sovereign class the crew compliment is of 885 (130 Officers; 725 Enlisted Crew) with a limit of 2,500 person capacity.

Given that Enterprise-E, as present in Nemesis, was a refitted Sovereign, the initial value of the crew compliment may have suffered small modifications.

Comment: What's your source for saying it was refitted? That doesn't make much sense given that it was only the second one made.

Comment: "Between 2375 and 2379 the Enterprise underwent a major refit. Four additional aft-facing photon torpedo tubes were added, along with one more forward-facing tube: a twin launcher aft of the bridge, a single launcher above the aft hangar deck, and a single launcher at the forward base of the bridge terracing. The bridge was refitted [...]consoles were improved across the port and starboard walls with more detailed displays. Additionally, new nacelle pylons were fitted at that time, [...], and fitted with four additional phaser arrays."  Source is Memory Alpha.

Comment: Okay, I'm wrong. Only three years between construction being finished and a major refit. I suspect someone was stretching credulity for cool special effects.

Comment: The war with the Borg drove technological advancement in the Federation, especially military technology.  3 years between upgrades is conservative.  Video game consoles barely make it that long.

Answer (score 4):

## Rob Durfee says 500

According to [this site](http://www.durfee.net/startrek/c_Sovereign.html), the crew complement of the *E* was 500.  Although most of the information included on that page seems right, alas I can find no source to back it up, but it's the only definitive reference to a crew complement I have found so far.

Considering the *Enterprise-E* was refitted (because in *Nemesis* we suddenly have more decks by *Nemesis*), it is likely that this figure represents the crew complement *prior* to the refit.  Post-refit crew complement would likely be closer to @Overmind's answer.